# How to change the tab width and height in android to work for all devices

Tags: android, layout, tabs

I found a method to change the width and height of tab, but I'm not sure whether it works for all devices or not.

This is the method.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(new
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/3)-2,100));
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(new
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/3)-2,100));

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(new
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/3)-2,100));
```

LayoutParams take height and width in int variable, so is there any way to change the height and width using some other method like changing in layout xml or some other technic?

Comment: XML is static so you can't change it there, XML is just for your initial layout.

Comment: while initialization only we can't specify width and height?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify width and height while initializing, but if you want get display width,height you can get it after draw is called.

Comment: I don't want to use techniq of drawing using device height and width

Comment: maybe you can use fill parent and layout_weight in xml.